# How to show that $f(x)=2x$ is not onto, as a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> $f\colon\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ is given by $f(x) = 2x$. Show that $f$ is one-to-one and not onto.

I know this is a very simple question but I can't figure out why this is NOT onto. I've done many other questions but this is the one I'm stuck with!

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Note that if $y\in\operatorname{rng}(f)$, then $y=2x$ for some $x\in\Bbb Z$, therefore $\frac y2=x$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the image of $x\in \Bbb Z$ by $f$ is $2x$: even integer so if we take an odd integer $y\in\Bbb Z$ can you find an antecedent of $y$ by $f$?